# .htaccess redirect to file if file exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do the following by using htaccess:

In the address bar: http://images.domain.ext/100x100/1234/some_text.jpg
On the server: http://images.domain.ext/100x100/1234.jpg

I already used:

```
RewriteRule ^100x100/(.*)/(.*)\.jpg$ /100x100/$1.jpg
```

This works, but it also redirect if the file doesn't exist.
I want the redirect only if the file exists on the server.
If the file doesn't exist, I want to go to the index.php

I think it's something with the RewriteCond -f, but I can't fugure out how to change the filename in the RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond /100x100/$1.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^100x100/(.*)/(.*)\.jpg$ /100x100/$1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce your Document Root as shown in figure 1 in [Regex Back-Reference Availability](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#regex):

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/100x100/$1.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^100x100/(.*)/(.*)\.jpg$ /100x100/$1.jpg
```